# Как написать программу на Pascal, а данные вводились из блокнота

Tags: массивы, pascal, pascalabc.net

Как написать программу на Pascal, что бы данные брались из блокнота, данные в блокноте (0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0), а в самом Pascal эти данные забивались в ячейки массива, размерность которого [1..12], после чего, нужно вывести результат из массива в паскале или же в отдельный текстовый документ.

```
program l;
  var f1,f2:text; 
  n,s:integer; 
  i:byte; 
  mas:array [1..12] of integer; 
begin 
  assign (f1,'inp.txt'); 
  reset(f1); 
  readln(f1,n); 
  for i:=1 to n do 
    readln (f1,mas[i]); 
  close(f1); 

  assign (f2,'res.txt'); 
  rewrite(f2); 
  s:=0; 
  for i:=1 to n do 
    s:=mas[1]; 
  writeln(f2,s); 
  close(f2); 

  writeln ('Второй файл'); 
  reset(f2); 
  while not eof (f2) do 
    begin 
      readln(f2,s); 
      writeln(s); 
    end; 
  readln;
end.
```

Comment: Записать данные в блокнот, сохранить в файл, открыть файл как текстовый в своей программе.

Comment: Это понятно, но у меня не получается код написать

Comment: Что именно не получается? Если у вас есть конкретные проблемы, то вам помогут. Но код за вас писать не будут.

Comment: Я прописываю код, что бы данные забивались из блокнота в массив Pascal, после чего, пробую вывести и ничего не получает, выдает все нули, а так не должно быть.
Все прописываю правильно вроде, а вот такие дела :(((

Comment: Приведите пример кода, пожалуйста, тогда мы сможем вам помочь

Comment: program l;
var
f1,f2:text;
n,s:integer;
i:byte;
mas:array [1..12] of integer;
begin
assign (f1,'inp.txt');
reset(f1);
readln(f1,n);
for i:=1 to n do readln (f1,mas[i]);
close(f1);  

assign (f2,'res.txt');
rewrite(f2);
s:=0;
for i:=1 to n do s:=mas[1];
writeln(f2,s);
close(f2);

writeln ('Второй файл');
reset(f2);
while not eof (f2) do
begin
readln(f2,s);
writeln(s);
end;
readln;
end.
вот что я наколдовал, но мне не выводится значения всего массива

Answer (score 1):

```
program FromFileToMassive;

const
  fin  = 'C:\Users\admin\Documents\in.txt';
  fout = 'C:\Users\admin\Documents\out.txt';
  n    = 12;

var
  fi, fo : text;
  data   : string;
  i      : integer;
  m      : array[1..n] of integer;

begin
  Assign(fi, fin);
  Reset(fi);
  for i := 1 to n do
    read(fi, m[i]);
  Close(fi);

  writeLn(m);

  Assign(fo, fout);
  Rewrite(fo);
  for i := 1 to n do
    write(fo, m[i]);
  writeLn(fo);
  Close(fo);

  readLn();
end.
```

Comment: Спасибо большое